# Python Dataframe merge with more than 1 index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, append

I need help to merge 2 dataframes by 2 indices (id or desc and year). I tried result = pd.concat([df1, s1], axis=1, ignore_index=True) but i'm not able to get it work.

```
df1:
       id   desc   year   value1
0       1   var1   2000       10
1       1   var1   2001       15
2       1   var1   2002      952
3       2   var2   2000       85
4       2   var2   2001       16
5       2   var2   2002       12
6       3   var3   2000      112
7       3   var3   2001       89

df2:
       id   desc   year   value2
0       1   var1   2000       44
1       1   var1   2001       33
2       1   var1   2002       22
3       2   var2   2000       11
...

To:
       id   desc   year   value1  value2
0       1   var1   2000       10      44
1       1   var1   2001       15      33
2       1   var1   2002      952      22
3       2   var2   2000       85      11
```

So the indices are id or desc and year to merge/append the new value2 to the dataframe. Any ideas?

Comment: you can use `df1.merge(df2, on=['id','desc','year'])` and optionally `how='left'|'right'|'outer'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try [.merge()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html), using `on=['col1','col2','col3']`:

```
In [24]: df1.merge(df2, on=['id','desc','year'])
Out[24]:
   id  desc  year  value1  value2
0   1  var1  2000      10      44
1   1  var1  2001      15      33
2   1  var1  2002     952      22
3   2  var2  2000      85      11
```